# Javascript / Typescript iteration over null-array not working with for of and forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, for-of-loop

If I have a null array and want to loop an object over every entry, but it doesn't work on the function loops.
Example:

```
const myArray = [null, null, null]
myArray.forEach(e => e = {}); // a console.log reveals that the loop is running 3 times
console.log(myArray); // expected: [{}, {}, {}] reality: [null, null, null]

for(let e of myArray) {
  e = {}; // a console.log reveals that the loop is running 3 times
}
console.log(myArray); // expected: [{}, {}, {}] reality: [null, null, null]
```

classic for works:

```
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  myArray[i] = {};
}
console.log(myArray); // expected: [{}, {}, {}] reality: [{}, {}, {}]
```

Do I overlook something obvious?

Comment: `const e` and `e = {}` is a bad pair, you should see an error in the console.

Comment: yes, thanks. will edit the question. I tried the for of in browser console and last second edited in the const *blush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, when you do:

```
let e = myArray[someIndex];
```

...you're **copying** the value from `myArray[someIndex]` to `e`. There is no ongoing link at that point between `e` and the array element, it's just that they have the same value. Both `forEach` and `for-of`, in different ways, are fundamentally doing the above. Assigning to `e`, in either case, won't have any effect on the array element `e`'s value came from. It's exactly like:

```
let a = 1;
let b = a;  // This does not create any kind of link back to `a`...
let b = 42; // So this doesn't change `a`.
```

If you want to replace every element of an array:

- If you want to update the array in place, use a classic `for` loop as you have in your question, or anything similar that gives you an index, and use that index to write to `myArray[index]`.

  or
- To create a *new* array of the updated values, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

  ```
  const newArray = myArray.map((e) => /*....*/);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

When you loop through the array you are passing the value to the callback. Primitive values are transferred by value and not by reference so you need to access the value using an index or you can just map the array to a new one

```
let myArray = [null, null, null]
myArray = myArray.map(e => e = {});
console.log(myArray);

const myArray2 = [null, null, null]
myArray2.forEach((e, i) => myArray2[i] = {});
console.log(myArray2);
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5vpxeozs/